# Identifying differences between the following sentences

Tags: grammar

If there are say, 5 people in a team, can anyone explain the subtle differences between the meaning of each of the following sentences?

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about the other.

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about rest of them.

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about anyone of them.

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about all of them.

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about anybody else.

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about anybody.

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about everybody.

And are these sentences correct too?

Or maybe I will explain it here what I think & anyone of you can let me know if anything is wrong or about what is their answer.

'Each of them wouldn't think bad about the other' means any team member wouldn't think separately bad about any other member in the same team.

'Each of them wouldn't think bad about rest of them' means any team member wouldn't think collectively bad about the other 4 members.

'Each of them wouldn't think bad about anyone of them' means the same as the 1st sentence.

'Each of them wouldn't think bad about all of them' means any team member wouldn't think collectively bad about all of the members (including him/herself).

'Each of them wouldn't think bad about anybody else' means any team member wouldn't think separately bad about anybody other than him/herself. The 'anybody else' here refers to any other person inside or outside the team but just not him/herself.

'Each of them wouldn't think bad about anybody' means any team member wouldn't think separately bad about anybody. The 'anybody' here refers to any person inside or outside the team including him/herself. (so literally anybody in the world). *Here I do have a doubt though- does 'anybody' include him/herself?*

'Each of them wouldn't think bad about everybody' means any team member wouldn't think collectively bad about everybody. The 'everybody' here refers to all people whether inside or outside the team including him/herself. (so literally everybody in the world)

Comment: Is this a homework question? And what do you think?

Comment: Nope, this is not a homework question. This is just what I came up now. I wanted to know if my answers to these are on the right track.

Comment: Is it appropriate for this site? Is it worth anyone's while? And we don't to proof reading here.

Comment: "Each of them wouldn't think bad about ..." isn't idiomatic.  This makes it pretty much impossible to interpret the subtleties of any differences.

Answer (score 1):

> Each of them wouldn't think bad about the other.

Better as: "None [of the group] would think badly about the other.", as

> wouldn't think bad

Is bad grammar:

- "Bad":  Adjective - of poor quality or a low standard.
- "Badly": Adverb - in an unsatisfactory, inadequate, or unsuccessful way, or used [*in this case*] to emphasise the seriousness of an unpleasant event or action.
- Belonging to the group is implied, or stated in you include "of the group".

Also,

- If you use 'Each' you are focusing the subject more on the *positive* action of the individual: "Each person [in the group] does the thing...", but there is a conflict of intention: A positive action to do a negative [bad] thing, whereas,
- If you use "None..." you are excluding the subject [*in a negative sense*] from the negative predicate act [wouldn't... Would not do the thing.], both parts of the sentence are in [logical] agreement.

The same applies to these:

> - Each of them wouldn't think bad about rest of them.
> - Each of them wouldn't think bad about all of them.
> - Each of them wouldn't think bad about anyone of them.
> - Each of them wouldn't think bad about all of them.

The same applies to these but, if the group is an important element, these are more vague about the individual's relationship to the group and imply the individuals actions may apply to anyone else in the world, not just the group:

> - Each of them wouldn't think bad about anybody else.
> - Each of them wouldn't think bad about anybody.
> - Each of them wouldn't think bad about everybody.

Comment: ['Think bad of'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/340364/which-one-is-right-think-bad-of-someone-or-think-badly-of-someone#:~:targetText=think%20badly%20of%20someone%20PHRASE,think%20bad%20of), probably modelling after 'think ill of', is certainly fairly common.